# Add rows.count to the first cell of a column

Tags: excel, vba, count, rows

I have Table1 which has 159 rows in column A. let's say the n = 159. I would like to use this number in another worksheet vba to determine the target range in Column G.Column G is not part of the table. I am used to coding in python and have a beginner's understanding of vba syntax. Would this be possible? Below is a sample of a code i researched in this site.

```
Sub FillDown()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range
    Dim strFormulas(1) As Variant
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")

    Dim k As Long

    Set rn = sh.UsedRange
    k = rn.Rows.Count + rn.Row - 1


    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Analysis")
        strFormulas(1) = "=IFERROR(OR(Sheet1!A1:Z1), "")"

        ActiveSheet.Range("F1").Formula = strFormulas
        ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F").FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

In this line: 
            ActiveSheet.Range("F1:F").FillDown

I would like to add the 'n':
`ActiveSheet.Range("F1 + n").FillDown`

But this one doesn't work. I am also open to any resources you can provide for vba syntax specially for complex formulas

Thanks!

Comment: `"F1:F"` is not a valid range reference: `"F1:F" & n`?

Comment: `"=IFERROR(OR(Sheet1!A1:Z1), """")"` - you need to double up inner quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Without really being able to test I picked up some mishaps in your code.

- You are filling an array with a formula? Just use a `String` variable if any at all.
- `UsedRange` is a very unreliable way of retrieving your last used row. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11169920/9758194) link for some explaination.
- You have not thought through how to use your `Worksheet` variable "rn". You `Set` it up, but when you actually want to use it in a `With` statement, you A) don't refer to your variable and B) went back to the evil `ActiveSheet`.
- `F1:F` Is bad VBA syntax. It's valid Google Sheets syntax which might have thrown you off. You'd need to concatenate the last used row variable in this case.
- To create a valid formula you need to double up the quotes in your string for VBA to pick up the `""` as a parameter in the used formula.
- You don't need to `FillDown` when VBA will auto-adjust the references in your formula.

See if the following does the trick:

```
Sub FillDown()

    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim rn As Range, k As Long, strFormulas As String

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis")
    With sh
        k = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        strFormulas = "=IFERROR(OR(Sheet1!A1:Z1), """")"
        .Range("F1:F" & k).Formula = strFormulas
    End With

End Sub
```

Though, the final result makes no sense since your formula looks wonky to begin with. Your next step in the process I'd say =)

Good luck.